# Setting the response and getting it

Tags: java, servlets, grails

I have a servlet and this servlet is called from a grails aplication as

```
def result = rest.get("http://localhost:9081/ServletSample/ServletSample")
```

where rest is

```
def rest = newRestBuilder(connectTimeout:"${Constants.WEBSERVICE_CONNECT_TIMEOUT}".toInteger(),
        readTimeout:"${Constants.WEBSERVICE_READ_TIMEOUT}".toInteger())
```

the servlet doGet() method does some logic and i need to send a response back to the grails application which then checks the response that i set in the servlet as

```
if (result.status == 200) {
    if (result.body == "Starting") {
}}
```

i tried to set the response as

```
response.setContentType("application/xml");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

but in the grails it is unable to recognize it. How to set the values in the response and also how to get it in the grails code

Comment: Content-Type tells server what format client sends in. Try setting Accept header to application/xml to tell server that u want to get XML format

Comment: i could not get what excatly you mean